# selectTabChange event is firing when mat-tab is loaded as it should be triggered when we select any tab after loading . Angular material tab

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular9

Trying to implement material tab angular

component.html

```
  <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabSelectionChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabList;" [label]="tab">
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            {{ tab.tabName }}
  </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

component.ts

```
tabList : any[];

ngOnInit(){
 this.tabList = [{tabName : "Tab1"},{tabName : "Tab2"}]
}

tabSelectionChanged(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

When trying to load the material tab in this way, selectedTabChange event is getting fired. Why does that happen as we are only loading the tab and did not change the tab by selecting the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and its working fine, the `console.log` is logging only on tab change, see this working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-44qece?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Yes, the code which I have posted seems to be working fine. Sorry that I cannot put the exact code .  I am trying to set the tabList through an API call which is observable.  With all this setup, on load, the tabChangeEvent is getting fired. I have also integrated agGrid in the same page, where on tab change a filter will be applied to the agGrid but both mat-tab and agGrid are independent elements. .